# Page freezing when using Chart.js in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to build a simple bar chart using Chart.js. When I try to view my page, my browser become irresponsive.

> The **Api version** is **40**
>
> chartjs version is **2.1.4**

- we are following [this](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) to build the chart.

**ChartJsApp**

```
 <aura:application >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.ChartJs}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>
    <canvas aura:id="chart" />
</aura:application>
```

**ChartJsAppController.js**

```
({
    scriptsLoaded: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var chart = new Chart(cmp.find("chart").getElement().getContext("2d"), {
            "type": "bar",
            "data": {
                "labels": [
                    "January",
                    "February",
                    "March",
                    "April",
                    "May",
                    "June",
                    "July"
                ],
                "datasets": [
                    {
                        "label": "My First Dataset",
                        "data": [
                            65,
                            59,
                            80,
                            81,
                            56,
                            55,
                            40
                        ],
                        "fill": false,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"
                        ],
                        "borderColor": [
                            "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                            "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
                            "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
                            "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
                            "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                            "rgb(153, 102, 255)",
                            "rgb(201, 203, 207)"
                        ],
                        "borderWidth": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "yAxes": [
                        {
                            "ticks": {
                                "beginAtZero": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        });
        
    }
})
```

**Note :**

i tried lastest version of chartjs and i got same behavior

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your browser should become unresponsive though. I tested with the latest version of the library and did not encounter any issues.

[image]

above, i just dragged and dropped a component using your exact same code, but with the latest library in a lightning community. did not encounter any issues.

Most likely a browser issue, consider sharing your browser and its version. additionally, check your browser dev tools to see if you get any errors on load (before your browser becomes unresponsive) Try loading with other browsers as well and share your results.

fyi: tested using Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115

Answer (score -1):

We faced the same issue right now. we fixed it by changing the API version 40 to 39 :)

Answer (score -1):

Chart.js in Lightning component is working with chrome 58.0.3029.110 version. But not with Chrome 60 version.